# firefox 3.x doesn't support background images in Pseudo-classes?

Tags: css, firefox

Is it a bug that Firefox doesn't seem to support background-image swapping in pseudo-classes or is it that the other browsers are doing more than they should be?

I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong... this works in Opera and Chrome (haven't tested in IE yet)...

```
.myClass{
  background-image:url('off.jpg');
}

.myClass:hover{
  background-image:url('on.jpg');
}
```

However firefox just ignores this.  I was hoping to avoid writing a javascript roll-over... this seemed like such an elegant solution, but I'm starting to suspect that I'm hosed.

Comment: Firefox has always supported this. Perhaps try clearing your cache and reload your page. If it still doesn't work, we'll need to see more code.

Comment: I don't know does it solution or not. But sometimes, FF makes me trouble with background, when I miss to set bg repeat. Try to add some attributes, no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-y. Also, try to positioning your image, top left etc... What you need, it maybe solve your problem. Sounds ridiculous but so is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is in quirks mode, presumably, and `:hover` has some weird behavior in terms of when it applies or not in quirks mode.  I suggest putting your web page in standards mode if you want browsers to actually behave compatibly on it, instead of explicitly asking them for buggy backwards-compatible behavior.

Comment: wow... I had never even heard of quirks mode! Amazing... adding <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> to the top of the document totally fixed it! thanks!

Comment: It's probably enough to just put `<!DOCTYPE html>` there (which also happens to be the HTML5 "doctype").

Answer (score 0):

What version of FF are you using?  A quick search revealed this possible issue similar to yours: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/746770

Try this to see if it works:

```
.myClass{
  background-image:url('off.jpg');
}

.myClass:hover{
  background-image:url('on.jpg');
}

[class="myClass"]:hover{  /* firefox fix */
  background-image:url('on.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I'm in 3.6.13 I should have started with that, sorry.  The above solution doesn't appear to do anything useful in my version.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version of FF and it works fine, so this is a 3.x specific bug... God how I  hate browser incompatibility!!! :/